# JAVA Multiple Operations when defining a variable

Tags: java

In Java is it possible to have multiple operations on a variable definition?

For example

```
double myLocalVariable = (myLocalVar2 + myLocalVar3 * myLocalVar4);
```

Thanks for the help!

CJ

Comment: I did try it and it did not work, hence the question. Thank you for taking the time out of your day to post useful responses.

Comment: I am not trying to offense you, but just curious why you raise this question. I have posted mine. Hope I can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and you can even perform multiple assignments inline:

```
double myLocalVariable1, myLocalVariable2 = (myLocalVar2 + myLocalVar3 * myLocalVar4);
```

or if they where previously created variables:

```
double x;
double y = x = 5 * 4 + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The result of the right hand side expression is used to initialize `myLocalVariable`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very much possible in Java. Of course, you need to take care of evaluation precedence to get the desired/correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. There are 3 methods to initialize a instance member.

```
/** Simple instance member initialization */
public double myLocalVariable = 10.234;

/** Method call instance member initialization */
public double myLocalVariable = <method you want to call> // e.g. ClassA.getNumber()

/** Complex instance member initialization */
private double myLocalVariable;
{
   myLocalVariable = (myLocalVar2 + myLocalVar3 * myLocalVar4);
   .....
   .....
   ..... 
   //even more complex operation you want to do
}
```

Certainly yours is also ok which is a simple instance member initialization.

Hope this help you.